# Scanner not taking input properly

Tags: java

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int T = sc.nextInt();
    for (int i = 1; i <= T; i++) {
        int xs ;
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int divisor = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < n -1;j++){
            divisor = divisor * 10;
        }
        //System.out.println(divisor + "/" + n);

        int[][] matrix = new int[n][n];
        int[][] matrix2 = new int[n][n];

        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
             int d2  = divisor;
             xs = sc.nextInt();
             System.out.println(xs);
           // System.out.println("\n"+xs + "df" + xs.length());
            for (int l = 0; l < n; l++) {
                matrix[k][l] =  xs / d2;
                matrix2[k][l] = 0;
                xs = xs % d2;
                divisor = d2/10;
            }
        }
        // System.out.println("Hello");
        matrix2[0][0] = 1;
        Node node = new Node(0, 0);
        node.dis = 0;
        node.steps = 0;
        node.c = 0;
        openList[0] = node;
        util_expl(node, matrix, matrix2, n);
        fun(matrix, matrix2, n);
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}//
```

My input for example is

1
4
0100
1110
1011
1010
but my scanner is getting stuck as it cant take the input properly. I paste the whole input at once
I am printing the line to check whether input is correct but the answer is something like
100
1110
1010
then it is getting stuck.

Comment: By "cant take the input properly" you mean that instead of `0100` you are getting `100`? Also we can't copy-paste and run this code because we don't have Node class. Please take your time and post [MCVE] (a.k.a. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org))

Comment: Can you tell what should be the value of matrix and matrix 2 after the input is given. What are you trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Because you Start from **1** and you are using `nextInt();`

Working example :

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("type how many values : ");
        int t = sc.nextInt();
        String []a = new String[t] ;
        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) 

            a[i] = sc.next();

            for (String item : a)
                System.out.println(item);
```

[image]

Comment: And you got some nice content too. One hint: **console** output is still **text**. You only use screen shots as "last resort" - so instead of screen shooting your console - copy/paste as (formatted) text instead ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion , i'll keep in mind!